# BASH comparing strings/integers error

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on this script to check pricing.
It gets to line 16 and shoots an error.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "   Date        Time     Price"
echo "-----------------------------"
while [ true ]
do

new_price=$(curl -s "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate" | jq -r ".amount")

balance=0.000001

if [ -z $current_price ]; then
current_price=0
fi

if [ $current_price < $new_price ]; then
ARROW="+"
else if [ $current_price > $new_price ]; then
ARROW="-"
else
ARROW="="
fi
fi

echo "$(date '+%m/%d/%Y | %H:%M:%S') | $new_price | $ARROW"

current_price=$new_price
sleep 30
done
```

Outputs error

```
-PC:~/scripts/ticker$ ./arrows.sh
   Date        Time     Price
-----------------------------
./arrows.sh: line 16: 7685.00: No such file or directory
11/17/2017 | 15:45:28 | 7685.00 | -
```

And this is the verbose

```
-PC:~/scripts/ticker$ bash -x ./arrows.sh
+ echo '   Date        Time     Price'
   Date        Time     Price
+ echo -----------------------------
-----------------------------
+ '[' true ']'
++ curl -s https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate
++ jq -r .amount
+ new_price=7685.00
+ balance=0.000001
+ '[' -z ']'
+ current_price=0
+ '[' 0 ']'
+ ARROW=+
++ date '+%m/%d/%Y | %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
if [ $current_price < $new_price ]; then
ARROW="+"
else if [ $current_price > $new_price ]; then
ARROW="-"
else
ARROW="="
fi
fi
```

With:

```
if echo "$current_price < $new_price" | bc | grep -q 1; then
    ARROW="+" 
elif  echo "$current_price > $new_price" | bc | grep -q 1; then
    ARROW="-"
else
    ARROW="="
fi
```

In test (`[`), the operator for numeric less-than comparison is `-lt` not `<`.  (This is because `<` is for input redirection.)  Thus, if your prices were integers, you could use:

```
if [ "$current_price" -lt "$new_price" ]; then
```

But, your prices are floating point so we need `bc` or equivalent to do the math.  `bc` prints `1` if a logical condition is true and `0` if it is false.  We follow that with `grep -q 1` which sets a proper return code that `if` can use.

Also, note that bash supports `elif` which provides simpler syntax than `else if`.  Lastly, many users think that indentation makes bash commands like `if-then-else-fi` easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I hate `if`'s, so, if I can avoid them:

```
arrows=('=' '<' '>')
ARROW=${arrows[$(echo "c=$current_price;n=$new_price;(c<n)+2*(c>n)" | bc)]}
```

In slow-motion: `c=$current_price;n=$new_price;(c<n)+2*(c>n)` returns 0, 1 or 2, if the values are equal, smaller, or bigger. This is used to index the array of symbols.